# In Grpc c++, Do I need to use asynchronous API for a client streaming rpc?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

```proto
`rpc fileUpload (fileRequest) returns (fileResponse)  {}
  
  message fileRequest{
 
    oneof request {
    MetaData metadata = 1;
    File file = 2;
  }

  message MetaData {
  string name = 1;
  string type = 2;
}


message File {
  bytes content = 1;
}`
```

I am working on a grpc c++ application. I am trying to send an image file from client to server. For streaming the file data as chunks to the server, do I need to use an grpc asynchronous API or can it be done with the grpc synchronous API itself ?

Comment: It depends on your server API. Are you designing the client and the server or only the client? Could you share the relevant bits of the proto file?

If the server API supports receiving data in chunks then you can send it in chunks. If the server API only supports receiving the entire payload then you would have to send the entire payload. My understanding is that streaming is orthogonal to this. Either API could be implemented to support client streaming or not.

Comment: Hi @GregKrimer. Thank you for your reply. I am designing both the client and server. If streaming can be done in synchronous API, do we need to use client reader and server writer. This is my proto rpc: `rpc fileUpload (fileRequest) returns (fileResponse) {}`... This is the fileRequest: `message fileRequest{
 
    oneof request {
    MetaData metadata = 1;
    File file = 2;
  }

}` This is the file message: `message File {
  bytes content = 1;
}`.... I am confused on how to send the request and get the entire file data at the server end for client streaming. Can you please help me ?